# How can I access the category.php page in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have created the `category.php` in my theme and added some code. The below code will display my category list. Now I want to know how can I access this `category.php` page?

When I am accessing the `mywebsite.com/category` then I am getting `Page not found`.

I added below code in category.php page

```
   <?php
   /**
   * A Simple Category Template
   */
   get_header(); 

?>  
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
   <main id="main" class="site-main">
       <div class="CategoryHero">
           <?php
// Get the current queried object
$term    = get_queried_object();
$term_id = ( isset( $term->term_id ) ) ? (int) $term->term_id : 0;

$categories = get_categories( array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'category',
    'orderby'    => 'name',
    'parent'     => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0, // change to 1 to hide categores not having a single post
) );
?>
<div class="categoryWrapper_list"><div class="equalPadding">
<ul>
    <?php
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
    {
        //echo "<pre>";
        //var_dump($category);
        $cat_ID        = $category->term_id;
        $category_name = $category->name;
        $category_desc = $category->description;
        $category_images = get_option('category_images');  
        
        // When viewing a particular category, give it an [active] class
        $cat_class = ( $cat_ID == $term_id ) ? 'active' : 'not-active';
        // I don't like showing the [uncategoirzed] category
        if ( strtolower( $category_name ) != 'uncategorized' ){?>
            <li> <div class="subCategoryPostWrap" style="background-image:linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)),url(<?php echo $category_images[$cat_ID];?>)">
                <div class="blackBoxPackage">
                    <div class="cp-b-content">
                    <h4><?php echo $category_name;?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $category_desc;?></p>
          <div class="canExplore">
              <a class="canbtn" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_category_link($cat_ID));?>">Explore now</a>
                </div>
          </div>

                </div>
                </div>
    </li>
                    <?php
                    
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
    </div>
           </div>
     
         </div>
   </main>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

according to WordPress template hierarchy

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

the category.php template gets displayed when the url has either category/{category-slug} or category/{category_id}

and WordPress looks for a file with the name

category-{category-slug}.php or category-{category-id}.php

if not found then goes for category.php

and if category.php does not exist, WordPress will look for a generic archive template, archive.php.

*** update *****

I guess I understood you now

[image: here I created a file page-{whatever name you want .. maybe cats}]

[image: then I create a new page with the same name (cats) for example ... if you want to use another name you should explicitly choose this file as a template for the page..]

[image: as you see here working as expected]

here I created a file page-{whatever name you want .. maybe cats

then I create a new page with the same name (cats) for example ... if you want to use another name you should explicitly choose this file as a template for the page..

as you see here working as expected

Comment: For example, If I create category-list.php then what URL I have to use it ?

Comment: I created category-list.php file and I am accessing URL like mywebsite.com/category/category-list or mywebsite.com/category/list  but both links are not working. I am getting page not found

Comment: if you have file category-list.php ... then category/list will go to that file   ... but do you already have a category with the slug (list) ?

Comment: I tried that but still, I am getting page not found. I added the screenshot in the question. Please check it once. No I don't have a list in my category

Comment: well .. look .. from your code snippet I understood you want to list all categories 

not to show all posts of one category as the example of WordPress ... so this is a custom page where you do the query yourself using get_categories function..

you may do something like naming the file ( page-categories.php )  
and access it using .

yourdomain/categories 

if still not working ... use it as a template explicitly 

/*
 * Template Name:Categories
 */

and from wp-admin create a new page and assign this template to it .. and modify the permalink of the page as you wish

Comment: Yes, You understood my issue. I created a page called page-categories.php and wp-admin created page called categories. Now when I am accessing the page mywebsite.com/categories then I am getting my category list. That means it's working.

Comment: I want to know, I created a page in wp-admin called as categories so that page always empty?

Comment: if you hit the url   /categories and find that the page exists then it's working

the page is always empty?? 

it shouldn't be empty .. it should display what's in you PHP file ( page-categories.php )

Comment: But in the wp-admin page categories is always empty. right? I have to add the code in page-categories.php page. right?

Comment: ah .. yes ... you mean you add nothing to the page from wp-admin ... yes .. you don't need to .. except if you want to use shortcodes or fill the page statically with static content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure this will solve your problem but you need to let WordPress know this is a custom template by writing an opening PHP comment at the top of the file that states the template’s name.

```
<?php 

/* Template Name: A Simple Category Template */ 

?>
```

Comment: No That is not an issue.

Comment: I'm assuming you tried it rather than disregarded it becuase it's very important. But perhaps you can try adding this below that comment. 
```Template Post Type: category```

Comment: The point is that your code is not important here. You've got an issue with telling WordPress to use your page at  this specific point. So any other information about your setup woiuld be more important. Using any page builders? what's the theme? Is this a cpt?

Comment: I am not using any plugin and I have my own custom theme.